# Link data.frame and matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` and a `matrix` with same row and different number of columns.

All elements in the `matrix` are integer but the `data.frame` includes character in some columns.

I want to link the rows of these file, i.e. if if I delete a row in the `matrix` the same row in the `data.frame` be deleted automatically or when I sort the elements of `data.frame` with one of its column, the elements in the matrix be sorted accordingly.

Added note: I want to keep the `matrix` as integer matrix so I can not use `cbind`.

Comment: `cbind` them together.

Comment: The problem with `cbind` is that the combined matrix become a charater matrix. I want to keep the matrix as `integre`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two solutions to this. The easy option is to make a new `data.frame` which includes both rows as such:

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:26, Group = sample(c("A", "B"), 26, TRUE))
mat <- matrix(rnorm(78), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(1:26, paste0("Val", 1:3)))
```

Make new `data.frame`, storing names of matrix columns for later reference:

```
new_df <- cbind(df, mat)
mat_cols <- colnames(mat)
```

Do some subsetting:

```
new_df <- new_df[seq(1, 25, 2), ]
```

Extract matrix back out whenever needed:

```
as.matrix(new_df[, mat_cols])
```

The other option is to use an S3 or S4 class. The Bioconductor package `Biobase` has, for example, an `ExpressionSet` class which can hold a `matrix` and phenotype data, and subsetting works to subset both (though the matrix has the rows and columns the opposite way round).

If you wanted to do that more simply (`ExpressionsSet`s can be relatively complex to get your head around), here's an S3 implementation:

```
as.JoinedUp <- function(data_frame, matrix) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(data_frame), is.matrix(matrix), nrow(data_frame) == nrow(matrix))
  x <- list(data_frame = data_frame, matrix = matrix)
  class(x) <- "JoinedUp"
  x
}
`[.JoinedUp` <- function(x, i = NULL, j = NULL) {
  if (is.null(i)) {
    i <- 1:nrow(x$data_frame)
  }
  if (is.null(j)) {
    j <- union(colnames(x$data_frame), colnames(x$matrix))
  }
  stopifnot(is.character(j))
  x$data_frame <- x$data_frame[i, intersect(j, colnames(x$data_frame)), drop = FALSE]
  x$matrix <- x$matrix[i, intersect(j, colnames(x$matrix)), drop = FALSE]
  x
}
`[<-.JoinedUp` <- function(x, i = NULL, j = NULL, value) {
  if (is.null(j)) {
    j <- union(colnames(x$data_frame), colnames(x$matrix))
  }
  if (is.null(i)) {
    i <- 1:nrow(x$data_frame)
  }
  stopifnot(is.character(j))
  if (!is.matrix(value) & !is.data.frame(value)) {
    value <- as.data.frame(t(value), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  stopifnot(ncol(value) == length(j))
  if (any(j %in% colnames(x$data_frame))) {
    df_cols <- intersect(j, colnames(x$data_frame))
    x$data_frame[i, df_cols] <- value[, match(df_cols, j)]
  }
  if (any(j %in% colnames(x$matrix))) {
    mat_cols <- intersect(j, colnames(x$matrix))
    x$matrix[i, mat_cols] <- data.matrix(value[, match(mat_cols, j)])
  }
  x
}
```

Examples:

```
new_obj <- as.JoinedUp(df, mat)
new_obj[1:3, ]
new_obj[, c("ID", "Val1")]
new_obj[10:15, ]$matrix
new_obj <- new_obj[order(new_obj$matrix[, "Val1"]), ]
new_obj[1:5, c("ID", "Val1")] <- data.frame(ID = 20:24, Val1 = 0)
```

This is only a skeleton of what you'd need; you'd probably also want to define methods for `dim`, `nrow`, `ncol`, etc.

Comment: I am completely impressed, although I knew S3 classes,  I did not know that we can overload `[` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(ID=1:3, x=letters[1:3])
m1 <- matrix(c(1:3,runif(6)), ncol=3)

#cbind data.frame and matrix, results in a data.frame object
res <- cbind(df1, m1)
res
#   ID x 1         2         3
# 1  1 a 1 0.2875775 0.8830174
# 2  2 b 2 0.7883051 0.9404673
# 3  3 c 3 0.4089769 0.0455565

#subset 2nd row
res[ 2,]
#   ID x 1         2         3
# 2  2 b 2 0.7883051 0.9404673

#order by 4th column
res[ order(res[ ,4 ]), ]
  # ID x 1         2         3
# 1  1 a 1 0.2875775 0.8830174
# 3  3 c 3 0.4089769 0.0455565
# 2  2 b 2 0.7883051 0.9404673
```