# Add rownames and dim to S3 class

Tags: r

Based on this question [Link data.frame and matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157791/link-data-frame-and-matrix) (Accepted answer), I tried to add `dim` to S3 class with this command:

```
dim.JoinedUp <- function(x)
{
    print(paste(dim(x$data_frame), dim(x$matrix)))
}
```

This function worked but there is a problem with `rownames`:

```
rownames.JoinedUp <- function(x)

{
    print(rownames(x$data_frame))
}
```

I get the `dim` results when I type `rownames(new_obj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `rownames` isn't an S3 method. See the definition of `rownames`:

```
function (x, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "row") 
{
    dn <- dimnames(x)
    if (!is.null(dn[[1L]])) 
        dn[[1L]]
    else {
        nr <- NROW(x)
        if (do.NULL) 
            NULL
        else if (nr > 0L) 
            paste0(prefix, seq_len(nr))
        else character()
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x3d0f2b0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

It calls `dimnames`, so you will have to create an method `dimnames` for your class. Something like:

```
dimnames.JoinedUp <- function(x) {
   dimnames(x$data_frame)
}
```